# Sending flac stream to google speech server via delphi

Tags: delphi, speech-recognition, flac, tstream

which is the best and easiest way to send flac data as stream to google speech server?
to get result as json file.
I have component (newac) to record audio as flac but couldn't solve how to send it's stream data to google speech server

Comment: You can find something close to your answer here: http://xiko94.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/google-speech-recognition/

Comment: Eventhough I have seen that before yes it is a good answer the thing is I did that and I need much faster technique for continious dictation mode

Answer (score 0):

who ever voted my question -1 this is for you

.I.

there are alot of brainless in this forum.

lets -1 this answer too.